# Может ли функция вернуть промежуточное значение при переборе словаря/списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Моя цель это перебрать словарь/список с другими вложенными словарями/списками и вернуть путь к необходимому мне значению. 
Сейчас при вызове функции она возвращает None, хотя если получить значение перед ним, то оно корректное. Мне кажется, что return не отрабатывает так как я предполагал и цикл продолжается.

**Входной объект**

```
b =  [
       {
           "id": "160407",
           "created": "2017-10-30T09:41:37.960+0000",
           "items": [
               {
                   "field": "status",
                   "fieldtype": "test",
                   "from": "10407",
                   "fromString": "Analysis",
                   "to": "4",
                   "toString": "To Do"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": "160407",
           "created": "2019-10-30T09:41:37.960+0000",
           "items": [
               {
                   "field": "status",
                   "fieldtype": "test",
                   "from": "10407",
                   "fromString": "Analysis",
                   "to": "3",
                   "toString": "In Progress"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
```

**Код функции**

```
def recursive(obj, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    # Check for object type and unpacked
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            # Write path for this key
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(key)

            # Check Status = in progress
            condition = 'to' in obj and '3' == obj['to']
            if condition:
                print(new_path) #Print correct value
                return new_path #None

            recursive(value, path=new_path)

    # Check for list type and unpacked
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(obj):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(i)
            recursive(item, path=new_path)

a = recursive(b) #None
```

Этот же пример https://repl.it/@IliaIeriomienko/recursive-function

Comment: У вас рекурсия, поэтому `return` возвращает нужное вам значение не в строчку `a = recursive(b)`, в предыдущий вызов функции `recursive()`. Вам нужно сесть с бумажкой и карандашом и внимательно проследить, что происходит.

Comment: @Эникейщик Точно, теперь понял, как это получилось
Будет ли выходом просто при соблюдении условий записать в глобальную переменную результат? Или это плохая практика

Comment: @Ilya Вам намекают на то, что уж коль скоро у вас рекурсия, то функция должна вызывать сама себя через `return`. То есть, внутри функции должно быть что-то вроде `return recursive(....)`.

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Да, возвращать результат в глобальную переменную плохо. Однако можно сделать вложенную функцию и использовать переменную из неё. Также, чтобы поиск был универсальным, можно условие вынести в аргумент функции, например, в виде лямбды:

```
def search_in_dict(obj, condition):
    results = []

    def recursive(obj, path):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            if condition(obj):
                results.append(path)
                # return

            for key, value in obj.items():
                recursive(value, path=path + [key])

        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for i, item in enumerate(obj):
                recursive(item, path=path + [i])

    recursive(obj, [])
    return results
```

Пример использования:

```
results = search_in_dict(b, lambda obj: 'to' in obj and '3' == obj['to'])
print(results)
```

На примере из вопроса получается такой результат:

```
[[1, 'items', 0]]
```

---

*Варианты улучшения кода*. `# return` можно раскомментировать для прерывания поиска или удалить для продолжения. Если ожидается лишь 1 результат, то `results` можно переделать из списка в один объект.

Дополнительно, в `recursive` можно добавить `return True/False` и проверку результата для прерывания итераций по словарям/спискам с целью экономии времени выполнения.